# Centrar Header de un GroupBox

Tags: c#, xaml

¿Puedo de alguna manera centrar el titulo `(Header)` de un GroupBox para que este se establezca siempre en el centro del propio control?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si hay alguna propiedad que me facilite hacer lo que deseo... Estoy revisando las opciones del control pero no veo nada que me valga.

Con la propiedad `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` solo consigo que el control adapte el contenido a lo que tiene, pero yo quiero que ocupe toda la columna del `Grid` que lo contiene adaptándose siempre al máximo al tamaño del `Grid`

```
      <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me estoy explicando bien...

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes extender la clase `GroupBox` de la siguiente manera:

```
public class CustomGrpBox : GroupBox
{
    private string _Text = "";
    public CustomGrpBox()
    {
        //ponemos el texto base vacío
        base.Text = "";
    }
    //create a new property a
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("GroupBoxText")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public new string Text
    {
        get
        {

            return _Text;
        }
        set
        {

            _Text = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

          //primero dejamos que la clase base dibuje el control
          base.OnPaint(e);
          //creamos un pincel con el color de la fuente
          SolidBrush colorBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
          //creamos un pincel con el color de fondo
          var backColor = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
          //mesuramos el tamaño del texto
          var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);
          //evaluamos la posicion del texto de la izquierda
          int left = (this.Width - size.Width) / 2;
          //dibujamos un rectangulo de relleno para eliminar el borde
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, new Rectangle(left, 0, size.Width, size.Height));
          //por último escrivimos el texto
          e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, colorBrush, new PointF(left, 0));

    }
}
```

Con la siguiente extensión de la clase estamos creando un control llamado `CustomGroupBox`, el cual deberás usar en el formulario para tener el texto centrado.

Comment: Madre mia... pensaba que en el XAML se podria hacer con un simple parametro... Creo que lo dejare a la izquierda, vaya manera de ensuciar el codigo en la parte del C# para conseguir lo que buscaba.
Gracias otra vez